# Why is the (principal) ideal $((\bar{1},\bar{0}))$ not free as a $R = \mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/2$ module?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Why is the (principal) ideal $$I = ((\bar{1},\bar{0}))$$ not free as a $$\mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/2$$ module?

The reason that D & F gives, is that every free module (by which I suppose they mean "every free $\mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/2$-module") must have an order that is a multiple of four.

I suppose the reason has something to do with the fact that $$\mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/2$$ has order $4$?

Could someone expand on why every $\mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/2$-module has to have order $4n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Depending on which definition of "free module" you're using, it may be easier to just note that $I$ is nonzero and $(0,1)I = 0$, but $(0,1) \in \mathbb{Z}/2\times\mathbb{Z}/2$ is nonzero.

Comment: It should say "every free module must have an order that is a *power* of 4".

Comment: Yeah, so not linearly independent you mean, @BrianMoehring? Good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R$ be a ring and let $M$ be a free left $R$-module of finite rank $n$. Then $M$ is isomorphic to
$$\bigoplus_{i=1}^n R$$
as $R$-modules. In particular, they have the same cardinality.

Now assume that the ring $R$ is finite of cardinality $r$. Then

$$|M| = \left |\bigoplus_{i=1}^n R \right| = r^n.$$

In your case, $R=\mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/2$ is a finite ring of cardinality 4. Therefore, if $I = \langle (\bar{0},\bar{1}) \rangle$ were a free module of rank $n$, then it would have cardinality $4^n$, but $I$ has cardinality 2!